# How to request Google Cloud Function (CF) from inside another CF?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, axios

I am trying to call Google Cloud Function (CF) with **axios** from inside another CF but I keep getting 
this error:

```
TypeError: A value undefined was yielded that could not be treated as a promise
```

I am calling `update()` from handler and it calls the `clientHasRightToEdit` before doing any db updates.

Here is the code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
var Promise = require('bluebird')

let clientHasRightToEdit = (req) =>{
   let clientToken = req.query.token
   let objectId = req.query.objectId

   let verificationUri = "[ANOTHER_CF_HTTP_TRIGGER]"
   return axios.get(verificationUri, {
      params: {
         id: objectId,
         token: clientToken
      }
    }).then(response => {
       if(response.data == "verified") return true
       else return false
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return false
    })
}

const update = (req, res) => {
   Promise.coroutine(function*() {
      let verification = yield clientHasRightToEdit(req)
      if(verification == false){
        return res.json({
          "code": "400",
          "message": "Verification failure",
          "body": "You are not allowed to edit this object"
        })
      }else{...}
   })()
}
```

In my package.json I have the axios dependency declared:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.31"
  }
```

What am I missing here. imo returning axios.get should return a Promise that will wait for resolve before the yield "moves on". I have tried many ways (syntax wise) to do the same but with the same error.

In other words, did I mess up with syntax here or there is something google specific here I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time solved this problem.

Today I wrote 2 very simple Cloud Functions: 1) Parent 2) Child with Parent calling the Child in the handler using *axios*.

I used the same Promise and yield approach (and syntax) as in the question and it seemed to work immediately.

Baffled I went back to the original code and it worked from the previous deployment.

It seems that it had a hard time starting up (I gave it an hour last time) but today 12 had passed.

Summary:

1. No problems with calling other cloud functions with axios.
2. This syntax is fine
3. Deployment requires more time than expected
   (over an hour this time) to work out. I suspect this is an exception, not a norm.
4. Cloud Functions are still in Beta!

Here are my test functions:

Child:

```
//handler
export const handlerSimple = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    return res.json({
      "code": "200",
      "message": "Success",
      "body": "This is child responding"
    })
  }
}
```

Parent:

```
require('dotenv').config()
var Promise = require('bluebird')
import axios from 'axios' 

let getChildResponse = (req) =>{
    let childUrl = [CHILD_CF_URI]
    return axios.get(childUrl, {
      }).then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return false
      })
}

//handler
export const handlerSimple = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    Promise.coroutine(function*() {
      let response = yield getChildResponse(req)
      if(response == false){
        return res.json({
          "code": "400",
          "message": "Error",
          "body": "Axios call to child failed"
        })
      }else{
        return res.json({
          "code": "200",
          "message": "This is parent responding, child in body",
          "body": response
        })
      }
    })()
  }
}
```